# SQL Between Date Range query working for some tables, but not others

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, ms-access, select

I've got 6 database tables storing information on commission rates and which rate to use depending on the customer/supplier/product and order date.

Using these tables, I have a procedure to calculate the amount of commission due to the user. This works fine for the first stages of the order, as it uses the current date, so my `SQL` is along the lines of

```
Dim p1Dt As New DataTable
Dim pDa As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Promotional Rates] WHERE Supp_Code=? AND " & _
                                "Product_Code=? AND Rate_Start_One <= DATE() AND " & _
                                "Rate_End_One >= DATE()", con)
pDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@supplier", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbSupplier.Text
pDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@product", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ugr.Cells("Product_Code").Value
pDa.Fill(p1Dt)
```

However, when the order has been delivered, the commission is then re-calculated with the delivery date for the product, which is taken from the database.

My code for doing this is a little bit different, since it isn't calculating it with the current date. Instead, I'm using this code

```
Dim deliveryDate As Date
deliveryDate = ugr.Cells("Final_Delivery").Value

Dim p1Dt As New DataTable
Dim pDa As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Promotional Rates] WHERE Supp_Code=? " & _
                                "AND Product_Code=? AND Rate_Start_One <= #" & _
                                 deliveryDate & "# AND Rate_End_One >= #" & _
                                 deliveryDate & "#", con)
pDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@supplier", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbSupplier.Text
pDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@product", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ugr.Cells("Product_Code").Value
pDa.Fill(p1Dt)
```

If I save the `Final_Delivery` value as 11/03/2017 (11th March), the `deliveryDate` value is being assigned as 11/03/2017.

I have a rate in the `Promotional Rates` table for all of March, so I'm expecting the above query to have 1 row in the table, however, it's returning 0, so is using the wrong values for the commission.

This doesn't happen when I use the `DATE()` method, it finds all of the rows in the tables correctly, so the issue lies somewhere in the way I'm entering dates in the second method.

Why would the second method not find the row in the database when I'm writing the query in this format?

**EDIT**

This is the full `CommandText`, after hovering over the `OleDbDataAdapter` variable and copy and pasting the `CommandText`

```
"SELECT * FROM [Promotional Rates] WHERE Supp_Code=? AND Product_Code=? AND Rate_Start_One " & _
"<= #11/03/2017# AND Rate_End_One >= #11/03/2017#"
```

The data in the database, to prove that it's got the correct dates in:

Sales Lines (For the `Final_Delivery` value)

[image]

Promotional Rates (For the date range)

[image]

Comment: You used parameters for supplier and product, you can/should supply the dates as date parameters.  The format and culture no longer matters (provided they are Dates in the DB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was, as @Plutonix mentioned, along with a couple of other people in a different forum - Using parameters to pass the dates in.

I completely forgot that this was even possible, in truth, but the way around the issue is parameterising the queries, such as:

```
 Dim deliveryDate As Date = ugr.Cells("Final_Delivery").Value

 Dim p1Dt As New DataTable
 Dim pDa As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Promotional Rates] WHERE Supp_Code=? AND " & _
                                 "Product_Code=? AND Rate_Start_One <= ? AND Rate_End_One " & _
                                 ">= ?", con)
 pDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@supplier", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbSupplier.Text
 pDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@product", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ugr.Cells("Product_Code").Value
 pDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dFrom", OleDbType.Date).Value = deliveryDate
 pDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dTo", OleDbType.Date).Value = deliveryDate
 pDa.Fill(p1Dt)
```

Comment: Hi, David, and thanks for contributing to Stack Overflow! However, please do not make [edits like this one](/review/suggested-edits/15485370). In particular, "iOS" is not program code, and thus should not be wrapped in [backticks](/editing-help#code). Please see e.g. [this answer on meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220) for guidance on how to properly edit posts (and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313517) for some examples of edits that are *not* helpful). Thanks! (Ps. I'll delete this comment in a few days, so that it won't clutter up this answer forever.)

Answer (score 0):

Access interprets dates in SQL strings as mm/dd/yyyy no matter what your regional settings are. Have a read up here http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html for some methods of dealing with it.

In the query designer this doesn't apply - which is very confusing. And it interprets Date() correctly no matter where you use it.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense - are you certain your data has the dates you are looking for in it? And that there is no time component in any of the values?

Comment: Okay - the first date will be read as 14/03/2017 because it can't be anything else, however the second one will be read as 03/11/2017 e.g. 3rd November because of the effects I described above. You have to force all the dates to mm/dd/yyyy format to work correctly

Comment: It returns 0 rows in both cases, though.

Comment: Well maybe I'm wrong about the first one being interpreted correctly. Force the date to the right format and see what happens.

Comment: Even that way around, 3/11/2017 and 3/14/2017, it still returns 0 rows.

Comment: How are you achieving that? try using Format(YourDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") ? This will remove any ambiguity.

Comment: yyyy/MM/dd or MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Well I would probably go with Allen Browne's suggestion "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") as  it's known to work regardless of location.

I use SQL Server as well so sometimes use the other version, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah, even using `Format(deliveryDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")` there are still 0 rows.

Comment: Maybe it's a vb.net issue then - try using yyyy/mm/dd - that's how sql prefers it.

Comment: Still nothing... Ah well

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should read:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Promotional Rates] WHERE Supp_Code=? AND Product_Code=? AND Rate_Start_One " & _
"<= #2017/03/11# AND Rate_End_One >= #2017/03/11#"
```

so modify like this:

```
Dim pDa As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Promotional Rates] WHERE Supp_Code=? " & _
                             "AND Product_Code=? AND Rate_Start_One <= #" & _
                             deliveryDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "# AND Rate_End_One >= #" & _
                             deliveryDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#", con)
```